# HP DL360 Gen9 RAM upgrade

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

I am trying to determine the details of each DDR3 chip: type/size. I would like to double what I currently have. 
DL360 g9 
128GB of ram

I am running ESXi and vCenter shows that I am utilizing 4 slots (e.g. Memory Device 1 04-P1 DIMM 1-6, etc...). I found this by going to the vmware vsphere web client -> selecting the host and selecting the monitor tab -> Hardware Status and expand Memory.

Soooo...math tells me I have 4 x 32 GB chips

*dmidecode* does not show that any slots are being used and therefore not providing me any good information.

Any other ideas on how I can get memory information of what is currently installed without having to use iLO or bust open the box?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the ILO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ILO interface to obtain hardware information.

For HP RAM, the part number, speed and health status are displayed there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it turns out that I had to do this regardless. I connected to iLO and voila noted that every single slot was filled and that there were a mixture of 8GB and 1GB pairs. doh!  Gotta love iLO, but man, wish there was another way too.